# How do you assign roles to users with the basic template in Yii2?

Tags: yii2, rbac

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#role-based-access-control-rbac

In the documentation, it says that you can assign the role to the user in the advanced template by using this code:

```
public function signup()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        $user = new User();
        $user->username = $this->username;
        $user->email = $this->email;
        $user->setPassword($this->password);
        $user->generateAuthKey();
        $user->save(false);

        // the following three lines were added:
        $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
        $authorRole = $auth->getRole('author');
        $auth->assign($authorRole, $user->getId());

        return $user;
    }

    return null;
}
```

The problem is that I am using the basic template. Is there a way of doing this inside the basic template?

I thought about using the afterSave method; however, I am not sure how to do this.

```
public function afterSave($insert)
{

}
```

Any idea on how it can be done?

```
public function afterSave($insert)
{
    $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
    $authorRole = $auth->getRole('author');
    $auth->assign($authorRole, $this->Id());
}
```

I am thinking this could work, but I am not totally sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not depend on used template.

Your example is correct, except few things.

`$this->Id()` should be replaced with `$this->id` (assuming primary key of users table is named `id`).

Note that you need also call parent implementation of `afterSave()` method and you missed `$changedAttributes` parameter:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */ 
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
{
    $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
    $authorRole = $auth->getRole('author');
    $auth->assign($authorRole, $this->id);

    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
}
```

For further improvements, you can wrap saving in transaction, so if something is failed in `afterSave()`, model is not saved (`afterSave()` event handler is executed after model is saved in database).

Also you can move assigning role logic to separate method.

Note that with this logic every registered user will have that role. You can wrap it with some condition, however it's better to assign role through admin interface.

You can see how it's implemented for example in [this extension](https://github.com/arogachev/yii2-rbac#gui). For example you can create separate form, action and extend `GridView` `ActionColumn` with additional icon for assigning role.